# data.tree in r how to add levels to existing nodes

Tags: r

learning to use the data.tree structure

so i created a root nod

```
alltree<-Node$new("all")
```

then i got a df that i can attach to it

```
f<-structure(list(parent = c("all", "all", "all", "all", "all", 
"all", "all", "all"), Kid = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", 
"H"), ID = 1:8), .Names = c("parent", "Kid", "ID"), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")

f$pathString <- paste("all", f$Kid, sep = "/")

alltree <-as.Node(f)
```

so far so good, but i wanted to add another layer

```
d <- structure(list(SUBZONE = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A8", "B10", 
"B11", "B2", "B3", "B4"), ZONE = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B"), ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L)), .Names = c("SUBZONE", "ZONE", "ID"), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

now how can i add it to the existing corresponding nodes? I do not want to recreate `pathString`, as it would wipe out the 2nd level fields ("ID").

```
d$pathString <- paste("all", d$ZONE,d$SUBZONE, sep = "/")
alltree <-as.Node(d)
```

Or is it just a tool limitation that I need to create it in one go - entire tree and then add fields/attributes? I have a tree 7 levels deep and would need to add attributes/fields at every level

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to do this with two separate data.frames, but we can just merge them into one data.frame and then plot it.

```
colnames(d)[1] = "Kid"
e = rbind.data.frame(f[, c("Kid", "pathString")], d[, c("Kid", "pathString")])

> head(e,10)
   Kid pathString
1    A      all/A
2    B      all/B
3    C      all/C
4    D      all/D
5    E      all/E
6    F      all/F
7    G      all/G
8    H      all/H
9   A1   all/A/A1
10  A2   all/A/A2

alltree <-as.Node(e)
plot(alltree)
```

[image]

Comment: i hoped there is a way of adding a level, this method would not allow me to add fields/attributes especially if their names/modes were different for every level. Merging it would require the attribute to be the same across all nodes

Comment: @Slav how many nodes are going at each level? You can add child nodes on individually

Comment: it is very substantial number. in general it is just a kind of prototype to replace selectize, something that you can basically type not only a name of a node but as well an attribute. Lets say if we imagine animals you can type either 'lion, or 'feline', or 'yellow mane'. Just a concept that i wanted to develop. Selectize would not let you use all attributes for the choice list, but nods can have many fields